# Convert Multidimensional String to Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I do have variable contains the complete string, which I need to be treated like Array. Like:

```
var events='[{"title":"Appointment","start":"10:30:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:00:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:15:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:45:00"}]';
```

Now, I need to treat and work that string like an array to pass that multidimensional Array to a function.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Try using JSON.parse(), passing your string as the argument.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to convert the String into an object with `objects = JSON.parse(events);`
after that, access is possible to access it with `objects[0].title`

See further details about json.parse here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Your code should look like

```
var events='[{"title":"Appointment","start":"10:30:00"}, {"title":"Appointment","start":"11:00:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:15:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:45:00"}]';
var objects = JSON.parse(events);
console.log(objects[0].title);
```

Another (but bad way) is using `eval()`. parsing the string with eval will execute the code and returns a result (In this case a javascript object) that can be accessed the same way. However, if you have malicous code in in the string, it will be executed as well. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

If you can, use JSON.parse().

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
var events = '[{"title":"Appointment","start":"10:30:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:00:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:15:00"},{"title":"Appointment","start":"11:45:00"}]';

var eventsArr = JSON.parse(events);
function myFunction(arr){
  arr.forEach(function(i){ // loop here to get information
    console.log('Title:',i.title + ' and start time:', i.start);
  });
}
myFunction(eventsArr); // pass the array here
```